# How do I prevent a column reference to an external Excel sheet from automatically incrementing?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to reference a column in an external Excel document in my formula, and then expanding said formula to the right to auto-fill the remaining cells. I have some values in the formula that I want to not auto-increment, which have been locked using absolute references ($), and others that should increment. But when it comes to the references to the external worksheet columns, those increment even though it makes no sense for them to do so.

Consider this formula as an example, with A1 through A* being a series of dates:

```
=COUNTIFS(external_sheet[date]; ">="&A1; external_sheet[status]; "ACTIVE";)
```

If I were to expand this formula to the right, it will increment [date] and [status] to the next column in the sheet. I do not want this behavior, but as far as I can tell there is no way to lock down these values as you can with absolute references. I tried adding a $ symbol before the external sheet reference, but that just breaks the formula.

An option would be to do `external_worksheet!$A:$A` instead, but for my use case it would make more sense to use references to named columns, as the order of columns may change between data files.

Comment: The references only change if, by 'expanding to the right', you mean dragging with the fill handle. Copying and pasting will result in formulas which continue to reference the same table columns. Even if you prefer to continue to use the fill handle, the solution is well-documented, and involves structured references of the form `external_sheet[[date]:[date]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after some more Googling (and learning that this is called a "structured reference"). Apparently, the syntax is this:

```
=COUNTIFS(external_sheet[[date]:[date]]; ">="&A1)
```

This will make sure that `date` does not increment to the next column name when filling to the right.

Thanks, I hate it.